# Why my overload inherit function is not hiding a base function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have this code:

```
enum type{FOO, BAR}

class base{
    funct(type t);
}
class other : base{
    funct(type t);
}

int main(){
    base x;
    x = other();
    x-funct(FOO); //This call base::funct()
}
```

Always call to base function, i dont get it.

Comment: i try also with virtual and override but... nothing

Comment: Try to use **references** and virtual functions, and you'll see it will work. So write something like `other oth; base& x = oth; x->funct(FOO);`, making sure `funct` is marked `virtual`. And also read the duplicate carefully, it explains quite a few useful things.

Comment: Does that even compile? `x-funct(FOO)` doesn't make sense.